# FaceBook Integration in PhoneGap App

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, cordova

I am working on facebook integration  in my phonegap/cordova app. I am following the link

```
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/
```

I am doing the same steps as mentioned in the article but the when I build the solution it gives the error ..

```
 Could not parse contents of /Users/Burhan/Desktop/facebookExample/facebookExample/facebookExample-Info.plist‌​': 
 The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted. 

  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>[**APP_ID**]</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <string>com.facebook.phonegap.myscheme</string>
        <array>
            <string>fb362599863837976</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I am stuck.Kindly help me.
Thanks in advance.
Burhan

Comment: what you have inside that file, post it here!!!

Comment: <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>[**APP_ID**]</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <string>com.facebook.phonegap.myscheme</string>
            <array>
                <string>fb362599863837976</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>

Comment: Nothing to hear from You ?? :(

Comment: buddy there might be issue in your plist file, i faced similar issue when i was working with cordova.plist, plz check any syntax coz thats the thing that corrupts a .plist file in the project.

Comment: Well dear i have already posted the .plist file syntax that i have changed kindly take a look at it and tell me if there is anything wrong .. :(

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-plugin-integration-for-PhoneGap-2.1-for-iOS-and-Android) is blog post which may be helpful for you, this is a more simply explained step-by-step process for integrating facebook plugin to a phonegap application.

Answer (score 1):

For future facebook integration with cordova/phonegap refer to the [Official Facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

Comment: I'd expect that to be in either Facebook or Cordova's repositories if it were official.

Answer (score 0):

function register_log_FB() {
    openFB.init({
        appId : '888864354512771'
    });

```
if (app_userid == 'undefined' || app_userid == null || app_userid == "") {
    console.log("No user_id so facebook login");
    app_userid = "";
    FBlogin();
} else {
    console.log("user exit");
    console.log("app_userid>>>>>>>" + app_userid);

    first_nameFB = "";
    last_nameFB = "";
    social_idFB = "";
    console.log(" >>>>>>>data>>>>lat " + rest_lat + " lng >>" + rest_lng
            + ">>fn " + first_nameFB + ">>ln " + restaurant_id + ">>rid "
            + last_nameFB + ">>tele " + telephone + ">>sid " + social_idFB
            + " >>img" + saveImg + ">>uid " + app_userid + ">>name "
            + re_name);

}

function FBlogin() {
    openFB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            getInfo();
        } else {
            console.log('Facebook login failed: ' + response.error);
        }
    }, {
        scope : 'email,read_stream'
    });
}

function getInfo() {
    openFB.api({
        path : '/me',
        success : function(data) {
            first_nameFB = data.first_name;
            last_nameFB = data.last_name;
            social_idFB = data.id;

            loadingMaybeSaved();
        },
        error : errorHandler
    });
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log("Server error");
}
```

}